# Looping a list of numbers against dictionary

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have a big list of phone numbers from number_list (taking from a file) and need to map against prefix number from the dictionary. How can I match against these 2 numbers?

```
number_list = [919865588453, 919613851649, 919869863504]
number_map = {91986 : 'Area 1', 9196138 : {'Area 2'}, 9198698 : 'Area 3'}

for number in number_list:
    for partialnum_ref, map_ref in number_map.iteritems():
        if re.match(number"\d", partialnum_ref):
            print "%d is in %s" % (number, map_ref)
```

Comment: are the keys in the dictionary always a minimum length? You could potentially get a lot of false positives if the dictionary is big enough..

Comment: phone numbers aren't something you'd want to do math with, you should probably use strings for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is `'Area 2'` in a set?

But, assuming that you want the most specific area:

```
number_list = [919865588453, 919613851649, 919869863504, 123456789012]
number_map = {91986 : 'Area 1', 9196138 : 'Area 2', 9198698 : 'Area 3'}

for number in number_list:
    for prefix, area in sorted(number_map.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1])):
        if str(number).startswith(str(prefix)):
            print "%d is in %s" % (number, area)
            break
    else:
        print "%d is in no area" % number
```

produces

```
919865588453 is in Area 1
919613851649 is in Area 2
919869863504 is in Area 3
123456789012 is in no area
```

If you want all the areas that a number is in instead of only the most specific one, you can remove the `sorted` and `break`.